# Pandas dropna function is returning original dataframe despite me setting a threshold. How may I resolve this?

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure why dropna() isn't working... 'data' is a preset pandas dataframe with 5 named columns with all values like integers or NA
Part of my project is to ask the user to input their own threshold by the way

```
threshold = input("What is your threshold for NAs in a given row?")
try:
   num = int(threshold)
except:
   print("Please enter a number or leave blank")
   if num < 0:
      print("Please enter a positive integer")
   elif num >= 0:
      data = data.dropna(axis = 0, thresh=num, inplace=True)
      print(data)
                
return data
```

[image]

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean here?

Comment: it isnt removing nas even if i set a threshold of 1 when I have rows that have 2+ NAs

Comment: Are you sure those values are actual `na`s and not e.g. the string "NA", etc.? :)

Comment: take a look at my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the indentation in your code, the only place where you actually end up running `dropna` is in the `except:` block if `int(threshold)` fails. :) That's why you always just return the original `data`.

You're missing the `except:` block's `else:` block:

```
threshold = input("What is your threshold for NAs in a given row?")
try:
    num = int(threshold)
except:
    print("Please enter a number or leave blank")
else:  # <- this!
    if num < 0:
        print("Please enter a positive integer")
    else:
        data = data.dropna(axis=0, thresh=num, inplace=True)
        print(data)

return data
```

Of course it would be better to just fail altogether and not return unmodified data.

```
def input_positive_integer(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            threshold = int(input(prompt))
            assert threshold > 0
            return threshold
        except Exception:
            print("Invalid input.")
            
threshold = input_positive_integer("What is your threshold for NAs in a given row?")
data.dropna(axis=0, thresh=threshold, inplace=True)  # inplace modification
```

Comment: legendddddddddd

Comment: strange just tried that first one and it still isn't working..